# Error while running phpmyadmin using localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, apache2

My problem is if i run 
    `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

it doesn't work but if i run 
`http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php`

it will work. Is there is something i have missed while configuring phpmyadmin, secondly how do i configure `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` path to work on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`.

Or is it something related to apache.conf file, if yes then how do i configure `apache.conf` file. I want my project and phpmyadmin to run on  localhost like if i run `http://localhost/` then it should run my project and if i run `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` then it should open the `index.php of phpmyadmin`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive, e.g.:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```